# How I can convert MPP to CSV file using Python script

Tags: python, automation, export-to-csv, ms-project-server-2016

I have got error regarding conversion from MPP file to CSV file.

I want to solve the following error:
Error occurred during conversion: (-2146959355, 'Start of the server failed', None, None)

The error looks like server. I do not have access MS project file. Is this the issue ?